# Q: How to differentiate two types of post?

Tags: website-design, gui-design

I am new to UX design and I am currently developing a design prototype for our project. Our project sort of a social media + shopping website. For our website, there are two types of posts: shopping offers and order requests. I have conducted a usability test already and some of the participants said that it was a little bit hard to differentiate the two types of posts because they look similar. How can I provide a more obvious differentiation for these two types of posts? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

[image: Shopping Offer Post Format]

[image: Order Request Post Format]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main difference between a shopping offer and an order request is that the offer has a specific object, if it's something to sell/buy, while the order is a transaction.

Without knowing what the project's design parameters are, what I would try to set as the main difference are these two concepts: the object and the transaction.

As an example, if the object of the offer is tangible, a title and the picture can definitely make the difference.

[image]